# xterm warning: Tried to connect to session manager

Tags: xterm, session

I am writing a quick script to read user input and put into commands of a couple different programs. I'm using `xterm -e` to open a terminal for each separate program.

The script is working fine, but each time `xterm -e` is executed, an error message is displayed:

> Warning: Tried to connect to session manager, None of the authentication protocols specified are supported

Any ideas on how to stop this from displaying?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`xterm` uses the `$SESSION_MANAGER` environment variable to find out how to contact the X session manager.

In your case it seems to be unable to authenticate to it. Possibly, that script is started in the current session but as a different user.

Anyway, you don't have to report to a session manager so you can as well unset that variable to make the error message go away:

```
unset -v SESSION_MANAGER
```

In POSIX-like shells (or `unsetenv SESSION_MANAGER` in (t)csh or `set -e SESSION_MANAGER` in `fish`)

Or if your `env` supports the non-standard `-u` option, start `xterm` as:

```
env -u SESSION_MANAGER xterm ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `xterm` does not directly use the `SESSION_MANAGER` variable.  That is used in the Xt and SM libraries.

A more direct method of disabling the session manager feature is found in the [xterm manual](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h2-OPTIONS), first in command-line options:

> [**`-sm`**](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#OPTIONS:-sm)
>   This option, corresponding to the  [**`sessionMgt`**](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Application-Resources:sessionMgt)  resource,  indicates that xterm should set up session manager callbacks.
>
> [**`+sm`**](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#OPTIONS:_sm)
>   This option indicates that xterm should not set up session manager callbacks.

and then in [application resources](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Application-Resources):

> [**`sessionMgt`** (class **`SessionMgt`**)](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Application-Resources:sessionMgt)
>   If the value of this resource is *"true"*, xterm sets up  session
>   manager  callbacks for `XtNdieCallback` and `XtNsaveCallback`.  The
>   default is *"true"*.

Since these features were introduced in [patch #169 (2002)](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_169), it is likely that they are available.

Answer (score -1):

You can ignore it with:

```
xterm -e 2> /dev/null
```